# Word for "a group of contests"

Tags: single-word-requests, collective-nouns

What is a word for *a group of contests*? It doesn't necessarily have to be a real word, just something that's concise and obvious, possibly something like *decathlon* but for an indeterminate number of events.

#### Update:

To add more details, I am not so much focusing on the group of contests themselves but instead on the context in which the contests take place. I believe **league** is the best I've come up with so far. i.e. an athletic league like the *Major League Baseball* vs *Minor League Baseball*.

I was also liking **Olympiad**, but the idea is that concept I'm going for is supposed to be an indeterminate time period and indeterminate number of games.

Comment: Maybe a competition?

Comment: Do you have a context? Otherwise this is very open ended.

Comment: A disappointment of contests.

Comment: Perhaps a "tournament".

Comment: @user20908  It tickled my fancy.

Comment: [FX Sitcom: The League](http://www.fxnetworks.com/shows/originals/theleague/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- If the series of contests is intellectual in nature, consider **olympiad** or **bowl** (Knowledge Bowl, Science Olympiad).
- Less so, then **bees** (spelling bees), and **-offs** (Face-Offs,
  Sing-Offs, Laugh-Offs, Dance-Offs).
- Individuals in mythology/religion persevere through physical **labors** and
  **trials** against deities and monsters (The Trials of Hercules).
- Sports has **matches**, **meets**, **jousts**, **bowls**, **rounds** and **round-robins**, **best of x**, **the games**. A creative modifier for games could work (see The Hunger Games).

If the word doesn't have to be real, you can try adulterating roots from Latin, Greek, or your own native language (**The Athleon**, **The Pugilics**).

Answer (score 3):

I'm reluctant to suggest a made-up word, but, in this case, you might consider ***polyathlon***.

After all, if a decathlon consists of ten events, a heptathlon seven, a triathlon three, etc., then it stands to reason that polyathlon would have an indeterminate number of events (much like *octagon, pentagon, dodecagon, polygon*).

Mixing unusual prefixes with -*athlon* isn't without precedent:

> Boylan admits that part of the motivation for his "nonathlon" is to
>   draw attention to LifeWise, a fitness facility on Brambleton Avenue. (*[Roanoke News](http://www.roanoke.com/sports/etc/wb/212255)*, July 18, 2009)

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't a "series" of contests do what you want?  "Season" is another possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Try "***contests***" as a mass noun to refer to a given set of contests.

(If "it doesn't have to be a real word", then this is better than a made-up word.)